# Execute query for each pair of values from a list

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g, oracle10g

I have a list of value pairs over which I iterate and run a query, the skeleton of which could be thought of like this.

list of pairs - ((x1,y1), (x2,y2), ... (xn,yn)) xi, yi are not all distinct.

q is an oracle query which returns a single value for any (xi,yi)

global_table is a single row table with

```
         id        col         deleted        
          1         Y            NULL
```

A few rows from 'table':

```
         id        col         deleted          pid            did
          1        NULL           Y              25             1 
         81         N            NULL            NULL          149
         101        Y            NULL            22            149
         61         Y            NULL            NULL          NULL
```

Also, there is a UNIQUE constraint on (pid, did, deleted) in table.

The query q goes like this.

```
          select w.finalcol from
            (select coalesce(a.col,b.col,c.col,d.col) as finalcol from
               (select * from global_table where deleted is null) a
               left outer join
               (select * from table where deleted is null) b
               on b.pid is null and b.did is null
               left outer join
               (select * from table where deleted is null) c
               on c.pid is null and c.did = xi
               left outer join
               (select * from table where deleted is null) d
               on d.pid = yi and d.did = xi
               ) w
```

n = 60

n is determined by another query which returns the list of value pairs.

```
           for element in (list of pairs)

                         q(xi,yi) (xi and yi might be used any number of times in the query)
```

I am trying to reduce the number of times I run this query. (from n times to 1)

I can try passing the individual lists   and  to the query after isolating them from the list of pairs but the catch is that not all pairs are present in the table(s) being queried from. But, you do get a value from the table for pairs that dont exist in the table(s) since there is a default case at play here (not important).

The default case is when

```
     select * from table where deleted is null
               and c.pid is null and c.did = xi

     select * from table where deleted is null
               and c.pid = yi and c.did = xi
```

dont return any rows.

I want my result to be of the form

```
x1              y1           q(x1,y1)

x2              y2           q(x2,y2)

.

.

.

xn              yn           q(xn,yn)
```

(no  pair must be left out, given that a few pairs might actually not be in the table)

How do I achieve this using just a single query?

Thanks

Comment: Is `q` a function or an SQL type? Or something else?  What determines `n`?  Also, the default case *is* important in providing a solution.  If you don't give us all the information we can't help you.  Why should we waste our time trying to guess what you really mean?

Comment: i have added additional details in the question. Also, in order to obtain the default value, i will have to run the query once.

Comment: You haven't added the query you're executing, the tables you're using or some sample data though... How is anyone meant to modify a non-existent query to do this for you?

Comment: added tables used and the query.

Comment: I see your question still hasn't been answered. Maybe it's asked in a too "mathematical" way. If still interested in having your answer, I suggest that you delete your question and replace it with a working SQL script that sets up the table structures over which you ask us to work, following by the simplest possible way of explaining what you need.

Comment: Example: Instead of `I have a list of value pairs over which I iterate and run a query ...` post a particular piece of PLSQL code which declares your list of value pairs and defines its values.

Comment: tried to follow this and gave up, here's where  stopped (when xi and yi are not present in the tables but used in the query) http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/fdf4b/7 it will help your case if you used real table names and columns names, then you wouldn't have to "translate it" as much and much more likely to get a result.